# How to apply drupal_add_css by block_id in Drupal?

Tags: blocks, theming

I am trying to apply css by block_id or block title.

```
if($template_name=="BOhhjI" && $block_name=="block1" ){
  drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('module', 'MyModule') . '/css/grid.css', array('group' => CSS_DEFAULT, 'every_page' => FALSE));
 }
  else if($template_name=="calender" && $block_name =="block2"){
  drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('module', 'MyModule') . '/css/carousal.css', array('group' => CSS_DEFAULT, 'every_page' => FALSE));
 }
 else{
  drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('module', 'MyModule') . '/css/MyModule.css', array('group' => CSS_DEFAULT, 'every_page' => FALSE));
 }
```

But, **drupal_add_css** apply css to whole page. I have a single template and multiple css.I need to switch css on a given condition. Any way to achieve this?

Edited: Following solution from comments

```
function Module_Name_block_view($delta = '') {
    $blocks = array();
    $query = db_select('Table Name', 'n')
            ->fields('n')
            ->execute();
    $block_data = $query->fetchAll();
  foreach ($block_data as $block_query) {
  $macname = $block_query->title;
  if($block_query->options == 'BOI'&& $delta == $macname){

    $blocks['subject'] = t($block_query->title);
    $blocks['content'] => array
      (
        '#markup' => block_content($block_query->selected_type_list),
        '#attached' => array
        (
          'css' => array('/css/grid.css'),
        ),
      );
}
  }
  return $blocks;

}
```

Comment: Where are you using that code (hook or function)? If you have a single template, why are you comparing the template name with 2 different strings?

Comment: http://www.montanaprogrammer.com/drupal/drupal-block-add-js-css/ with https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_view_MODULE_DELTA_alter/7 should do it.

Comment: There is a list of template names. That list basically provides different css implementation on the same template. So multiple css is applied on single template for each block.

Comment: You can't do that. Function hook_block_view() define for new block by your module. If other block create by other module, you want add css you can use [hook_block_view_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_view_alter/7). And i think better you can use hook_preprocess_block(&$vars) with this function you can add file css easy.

Comment: In hook_preprocess_block, I am giving condtion: `if($variables['block_html_id']=='grid-block'){
    drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('module', module_name') . '/css/grid.css'); 
}` and drupal_add_css is applied to every block on that page while I mentioned it to  apply on particular block id.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code. Paste this code in file template.php

```
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_block(&$vars) {
  // use dpm($vars) to see struct of variable $vars
  $delta = $vars['block']->delta;
  switch ($delta) {
    case 'abc':
      //add css here
      break;
  }
}
```

Block ID are

- string 'block'
- $variables['block']->module
- $variables['block']->delta

You can check block delta to use drupal_add_css()

Comment: I wanna use this in hook_block_view in .module file.

Comment: yes, you can replace yourtheme with your name module.

Comment: If you use in hook_block_view why you don't check $delta and use drupal_add_css?

Comment: I edit in hook_block_view, Can you please correct me, where I am doing wrong.

Comment: I commented in you question. And i think you should use this function. If you need more condition you can use dpm($vars) to see that.

Comment: It seems like drupal_add_css works for page not for individual block. Because when i am applying drupal_add_css for a particular block that has template name specified, css get applied to every block on that page. Is there any way to apply css for individual block not for whole page?

Comment: No. Function drupal_add_css() will store data in a array. And this array will process to $style in file htm.tpl.php. When you call drupal_add_css() and type is not **INLINE** this file will add to header or footer of page. In you case, you can do it with way of @Vimal Goradiya.

Answer (score 0):

I think block class module https://www.drupal.org/project/block_class would be suitable for this. All you need to do is add class or id to block and using this and mention css property of that class in your style.css. This module can be use on custom as well contrib.